# I am unable to connect with my online phpmyadmin mysql database which i created for testing my windows forms application

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin, database-connection

[error message from microsoft sql server management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/610tF.jpg)I set up a free phpmyadmin mysql database (online) and would like to use it for testing purposes on my windows forms application. I've been trying to connect to it from Microsoft server management studio and from visual studio but it always gives me the following error:

### title: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to xxx.xx.xxx.xx(purposely ex'd out)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

---

BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------[connection error message[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dfqy.jpg)

If anyone can give me detailed steps on how to resolve this, I'll really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB installation. It's not an API that your Windows Forms application can access. You'll have to connect directly to the database (over the standard port 3306) or use some sort of API that's hosted alongside the database.

Most hosting providers block incoming connections on 3306, certainly I would expect a free MySQL hosting provider to do that as well. You'll have to ask the hosting provider if you're able to connect from your local machine to the database machine; you may need to add your IP address to a list of allowed hosts, for instance. Often, it's a bad idea to expose your MySQL installation directly to the internet (for security and performance reasons).

Your error message mentions named pipes. Named pipes are a Windows method for inter-process communication that is usually meant to be accessed from the same local machine (I believe Windows technically allows using a named pipe through a local network connection, but you're certainly not on the same local network segment and your chances of the free hosting provider allowing you a way to access a named pipe from across the network are less than them opening up MySQL's port 3306). Somehow you'll have to adjust your connection string to connect via IP address or host name instead of named pipe.

And finally, your error message refers to SQL Server. Microsoft SQL Server is a very different database product from MySQL/MariaDB. If your code is expecting to connect to SQL Server, you won't be able to use a MySQL or MariaDB backend instead. The two products are different enough and even use different ports, so the code won't be able to connect.